# Can 2 Apps Access the 1 Sterling NoSQL Database?

Tags: sterling-db

I'm currently working with SterlingDB (not the phone 7 version) and would like to be able to access the same Sterling Database from 2 different applications (and therefore different AppDomains).

I have ascertained that even when you pass a FileSystemDriver to the RegisterDatabase method:

```
engine.SterlingDatabase.RegisterDatabase<PodcastDatabase>(new FileSystemDriver("MyTestApp/"));
```

you end up with 2 different databases:
I:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Sterling Database\TestMeGo\1123790033 and
I:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Sterling Database\TestMeGo\1728918701

This is presumably because the apps are contained in separate AppDomains and the IsolatedStorage which is used by Sterling is compartmentalised accordingly.

Is there a way to have just one Sterling database which more than 1 app can access?

Thanks

Comment: Posted on SterlingDB forums: http://sterling.codeplex.com/discussions/357947 I think you'll get an answer faster now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible, as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637555/can-two-silverlight-applications-share-isolatedstorage-on-one-machine). You either let the storage be based on the XAP url, or on the source domain. If you can get both apps to be from the same source domain, and use the [GetUserStoreForSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.getuserstoreforsite%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method, you should be able to get it to work.

Comment: Wow. This was a while back. I'm going to accept this as the answer. But I don't have time to go back and see if it will work. I went with sqlite, where I knew what I was doing. But your answer makes sense.